# Using "using" in public to inherit private constructor does not make it public

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

"using" a private member variable makes it a public member but the constructor stays private. Example:

```
class MyClass;

class Base
{
  private:
    Base(float v) : m_v{v} {}
    float m_v;

    friend MyClass;
};

class MyClass: public Base
{
  public:
    using Super = Base;

    using Super::Super; // this is still private
    using Super::m_v; // this is public
};

int main()
{
  MyClass x{3.4f}; // error - calling a private constructor of class 'Base'
  (void)x.m_v; // not an error

  return 0;
}
```

Is there any other way other than writing an universal ctor like this?

```
template<typename... Args>
MyClass(Args&&... args) : Super(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but can't you just add `public: MyClass(float v) : Super(v) {};` to `MyClass`?

Comment: I think that writing a public constructor (or constructors, such as your universal constructor) in `MyClass` is your only viable option, I'm afraid.  I would love to be proved wrong, though!

Comment: Small note, you can simplify the example by using `protected:` instead of `private:`. That way you can drop the `friend` declaration and the forward declaration of `MyClass`.

Comment: It is a very simplified version - I have multiple derived classes with a base with more than 1 argument. And a CRTP. So writing "using Super::Super" everywhere is much simpler.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The point is that by using a `using` statement, you can pull in all constructors. In this case `Base` only has one constructor, but should you decide to add another, you would have to remember to add it to `MyClass` and any other derived class that could make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors contains the following passage :

> **It has the same access as the corresponding base constructor.** It is constexpr if the user-defined constructor would have satisfied constexpr constructor requirements. It is deleted if the corresponding base constructor is deleted or if a defaulted default constructor would be deleted (except that the construction of the base whose constructor is being inherited doesn't count). An inheriting constructor cannot be explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized.

*It* refers to the inherited constructor. I'm not sure why, but it would appear that your approach is explicitly forbidden. The usual solution is to define a universal forwarding constructor.